# scripting - delayedexpansion - outside of the for loop

Tags: batch-file, scripting, dos, delayedvariableexpansion

I am trying to use the variable outside of the For loop. The echo inside the loop gives the result as expected. it is not working when i echo the variable outside of the loop. below is the script-

```
'SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET x=0
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%InPath%*_Out.txt" /b') DO (
SET /a x+=1& SET /a cnt+=1& SET Fname%x%=%%a& SET FDate%x%=!Fname%x%:~0,8!
ECHO %x% !cnt! !Fname%x%! !Date%x%!
)

set z=3
ECHO !FDate%z%! `
```

Comment: So - what is the routine showing, what is the result you see and what is the result you expect?

Comment: Full details on array management in Batch files are given at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 1):

What you have  here is a bad interpretation of what you see. The `for` loop does not work (determined from what you are trying to do outside of the `for` loop).

This

```
Fname%x%=%%a
SET FDate%x%=!Fname%x%:~0,8!
```

is executed inside the loop. There is no delayed expansion over the `x` variable, so, changes in the value of the variable are not visible inside the `for` loop and all the iterations are executed as

```
Fname0=%%a
SET FDate0=!Fname0:~0,8!
```

So, your claim that the code in the `for` loop works is not correct. Since it is not working, the code outside the `for` will not work as intended

You need something like

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%InPath%*_Out.txt" /b') DO (
    SET /a x+=1
    SET /a cnt+=1
    SET "Fname!x!=%%a"
    for %%b in (!x!) do (
        SET "FDate!x!=!Fname%%b:~0,8!"
        ECHO !x! !cnt! !Fname%%b! !FDate%%b!
    )
)
```

This will properly populate the "arrays" so your code outside the `for` loop will work